# Why is it not possible to use a hashed password to log in?

Tags: hash

When a hacker gets the hash of a password and knows how the client usually sends the data to the server, why is it not possible for the hacker to just build another application that sends the username and the hash (without hashing it again) to the server to log in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question makes no mention of salt/pepper, we'll stick to plain hashing of password (a terrible idea by the way). I'm assuming we're doing server-side hashing, as client-side hashing is also a terrible idea.

Let's denote the following:

- $P$: the password
- $H(P)$: the hashed password

You enter $P$ in the login form of the website. The backend computes $H(P)$ by running it $N$ (let's say 1000) times through `sha-256` (just to pick one). The backend looks up your user entry in its database and checks whether the computed $H(P)$ matches the $H(P)$ stored as your password. If it does: congratulations, you're you. Otherwise, "wrong password".

Now, an attacker got his grubby little hands on a dump of the database's user entries, including username and the $H(P)$ for each user. However, the attacker does not have direct access to the database.

The attacker goes to the website, types in your username and $H(P)$ as your password. The backend computes the hash of your password: $H(H(P))$. But lo and behold, $H(H(P)) \neq H(P)$ because one is hashed $2*N$ times, the other $N$ times.

All that's left is for the attacker to try to get the original password out of the dump of hashes. But this is a story for another day.

PS: if you do want to do client-side hashing, you still need to do server-side hashing. The stored value in the database would be $H_{server}(H_{client}(P))$. Never store client-side hashes, that's just as bad as storing the password.